# When opening QML FileDialog the application hangs indefinitely

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The below code worked before, but is not working anymore, to me, for unknown reasons:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    title: ""
    folder: "file:///home"
    signal file_opened(var filename)
    onAccepted: {
        file_opened(fileDialog.fileUrls)
        fileDialog.close()
    }
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true
}
```

I was using `shortcuts.home` but that also stopped working. Is there anything inherently wrong with the above?

Comment: You don't need to close the dialog in `onAccepted`, it calls its own close function while accepting.

Comment: What's not working exactly? can't reproduce the issue .. try to delete build folder and rebuild

Comment: Connecting to `file_opened` was the issue. I had to create a parent item and put the `signal` there and have the `filedialog` call it `onAccepted`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to open the dialog:

```
Component.onCompleted: open()
```

And remove the close() call as mentioned by other answers.

Comment: Try removing `folder: "file:///home"`